# does it exists the concept of per user subject, a kind of sub-tag subjects hosted by each user

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have answered some questions on StackOverflow. Many times, on a given tag, questions, very similary, but not exactly the same comes.

if it does not exist, it would be interesting if users, can host subjects folders, for which they can choose the title and inside which they can put shortcut to questions or answers. In other words it can be a sort 'favorites' organisation that a user can share with other users.

---

(edited)
My proposal is not clear, but it can be useful to find a way to group same questions and same answers.

I just need to classify my favorites into folders, and perhaps publish these folders as meta subjects.

Comment: It's my fisrt question on Meta-StackOverflow, I just woul like to understand the down-votes ?

Comment: A down vote on meta doesn't mean the same as on SO: it means that someone doesn't agree with your suggestion, doesn't think it's useful or should be implemented. Think of it as a "No, thanks."

Comment: Downvotes on meta can mean "this is a poorly written question" or "I disagree with you"

Comment: So in this cas, I'am not able to  know if it's 'poorly written', or 'not agree' or both. whatever, it's a bit strange to down-vote without explanation.

Comment: I haven't voted yet, but personally I'm having a hard time understanding your request.  You want each tag to have a set of "favorites" picked by users that point to the most common questions for that tag?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for here either.

Comment: It's not strange at all to downvote without explanation. Why should downvotes require explanation when upvotes don't? I've stopped explaining because I'm tired of people's repeated whining. Looks like there's no stopping it, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think people are downvoting your idea because its isn't very useful:

- you have [list of your answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608772/jpblanc#qpage_1-anpage_1-qsort_votes-ansort_newest)
- you have [list of your answers on target tag(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:608772%20%5Bc#%5D%20%5Bactive-directory%5D) - you can combine the tags to search
- you have [your favorites](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608772/jpblanc?tab=favorites)

More folders in this situation are unnecessary, IMO.
Why do you need group the questions, say, for [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and [.net](/questions/tagged/.net), in new folder?
Duplicate questions needs to be flagged, not answered and categorized.

Comment: I understand, but if you look at stackOverflow, Lots of answers are quite the same, it exists nothing to group same answers. My proposal is not clear, but it can be useful to find a way to group same questions and same answers.

Comment: @JPBlanc Disagree. None of questions are the exactly duplicate, and you can differ questions by tags.

Comment: My opinion is that there are a lot of duplicate, people copy/paste or rewrite answers changing context or examples to make reputation. All that need to be refactorised

Comment: @JPBlanc I think you better need to flag that than refactor it.

Comment: @JPBlanc: If "lots of answers are quite the same", then you should be flagging those questions as duplicates. Still don't see the problem here.